# Zlib version used in openjdk 11

Tags: zlib, openjdk-11

I am trying to check what zlib version is used for an specific version of openjdk 11 but I can't find it anywhere.
I was googling it but can't find it anywhere. I can just find some tickets in which it's informed that it has been updated.

Comment: Can you share the tickets you found which state that it has been updated

Answer (score 0):

The code is here:
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/tree/master/src/java.base/share/native/libzip
and current version should be 1.2.11